# Google Analytics Liked Tool to Detect Visitor IP Address

Tags: google-analytics

I was wondering is there any free google analytics tool, which I can detect my visitor IP address? I try to use statcounter, but they are only limit the log to 500 entries.

The reason I ask, because I want to detect Adsense click fraud activity on my web site.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at your web server logs to see all page requests and the associated IP address. And most log analyzers will also tell you how many unique visitors (by IP) you have. But I don't know what you hope to achieve. [Google already tracks click fraud](http://www.suite101.com/content/what-is-click-fraud-a124697) by IP address and other factors. So I don't think you'll be able to detect click fraud that Google hasn't already caught, especially if you don't have any expertise in web analytics.

Comment: I use a completely free hosting from sourceforge, and do not have access to log file.